# Follow move/resize events with HTML5 video?

Tags: html, resize, html5-video, move, onchange

When resizing a video and/or moving its position on the page, is there anyway to detect this using events? Or do I need to setup a timer and keep track of size and position changes manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `window` object has a native `onresize` event, so you'll need to do your own detection, possibly in the way you mentioned.   Instead of a timer you could also hook into mouse events and do the resize test on mouse up or similar events.

[Source: developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onresize)